# SQL query to search Custom taxonomy In wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I was trying develop a custom search box and I want to search custom post type taxonomy and I found this SQL query useful but there is one small problem, This query search all the available taxonomy on the database you can see my picture:

[image]

I search for green color from product category (woocommerce) but there is no such category created at my site this is coming from attribute taxonomy

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT wp_terms.term_id,wp_terms.name 
FROM wp_terms 
inner JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat' 
AND wp_terms.name like "green%";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For INNER JOIN you need ON to relate the data

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_terms.term_id,wp_terms.name 
FROM wp_terms 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat' AND wp_terms.name like "green%";
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother, It's working fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Please flag this as the correct answer if it fixed your issue as it helps others quickly if they run into something similar.